# I want to show the detail of specific order when I click on button but it get rendered on every order as this is in for loop

Tags: angular

```
<tbody>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let orderdetail of listoforderdetail.listoforders">
    <tr>
      <td>{{orderdetail.orderId}}</td>
      <td>{{orderdetail.ammount | currency:"Rs. "}}</td>
      <td>{{datepipe.transform(orderdetail.orderDate,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')}}</td>
      <td><button class="btn primary sm" (click)="details=true">Details</button></td>
    </tr>
    <div *ngIf="details">detail will come here when we click on button on specific ordder</div>
  </ng-container>
</tbody>
```

when I click on detail button of any row of order table ,the detail get rendered but it get rendered below each row as my button and div is in for loop .
When I click the button, I want the specific order detail to appear.

[image]

Comment: As you are using the same variable `details` in the loop, all the rows would show the details on click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears below each row, because details is a global variable, which is shared with all the rows. Therefore, once you click on the button, details become true, and the ngif condition becomes true for each row.

You need to have a condition depending on the row itself, so only the selected row become visible

```
<tbody>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let orderdetail of listoforderdetail.listoforders">
        <tr>
            <td>{{orderdetail.orderId}}</td>
            <td>{{orderdetail.ammount | currency:"Rs. "}}</td>
            <td>{{datepipe.transform(orderdetail.orderDate,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')}}</td>
            <td><button class="btn primary sm" (click)="orderdetail.visible=true">Details</button></td>
        </tr>
        <div *ngIf="orderdetail.visible">detail will come here when we click on button on specific ordder</div>
    </ng-container>
</tbody>
```

Comment: @bipin I edit my answer to have a snippet code, is my solution clear enough now?

Comment: like in the code snipped.
If you don't want to change your model, you could manage the state of a single row in a "Dictionary"/Object defined on your component.
Like `OrderVisibility[orderdetail.id]=true` and then check for `OrderVisibility[orderdetail.id]` in your detail.

Comment: @bipin as Arikael says, the good way to congratulate someone is to accept his answer, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) from the help page

Answer (score 1):

there are multiple issues here.

First your html output will be wrong because you can't have `<div>` in `<table>`.
you should change it something like

```html
<tr>
  <td colspan="4" *ngIf="[your-condition]">
    <div *ngIf="details">detail will come here when we click on button on specific ordder</div> 
  </td>
</tr>
```

Second you only have one variable `details` which you set with `(click)`.
Every `<div *ngIf="details">` checks for this variable (the same instance)

You can either move everything in `<ng-container>` into a own component or use @Kepotx approach who beat me by seconds with his answer ;)

Comment: i got your first point ,and i changed my code as u suggested but how my main problem is getting details of specfic order how can i solve this????

Comment: like in Kepotx answer, I personally would manage the state of a row in my component and not in orderdetail.
But that's an implementation detail and preference. Kepotx answer should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with this. Firstly, you can’t have a `<div>` as a sibling of a `<tr>`. HTML validity aside, the main problem is that you’re reusing the `details` variable for each item in the loop. Therefore when `details=true` for one it's true for all. You need to have a locally scoped variable for each item in your loop. I'm no Angular coder and I don't have a way to test this but something like this should work.

```
<tbody>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let orderdetail of listoforderdetail.listoforders">
    <tr>
      <td>{{orderdetail.orderId}}</td>
      <td>{{orderdetail.ammount | currency:"Rs. "}}</td>
      <td>{{datepipe.transform(orderdetail.orderDate,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')}}</td>
      <td><button class="btn primary sm" (click)="orderdetail.showdetails=true">Details</button></td>
    </tr>
    <div *ngIf="orderdetail.showdetails">detail will come here when we click on button on specific order</div>
  </ng-container>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can do something like this

```
<tbody>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let orderdetail of listoforderdetail.listoforders; let i = index">
    <tr>
      <td>{{orderdetail.orderId}}</td>
      <td>{{orderdetail.ammount | currency:"Rs. "}}</td>
      <td>{{datepipe.transform(orderdetail.orderDate,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')}}</td>
      <td><button class="btn primary sm" (click)="details + i=true">Details</button></td>
    </tr>
    <div *ngIf="details + i">detail will come here when we click on button on specific ordder</div>
  </ng-container>
</tbody>
```